# Two query hitting the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

If two separate queries running at same time hits a table at the same time, will the run time of individual query increase??

Thanks

Comment: Even two queries using different tables may increase the time (somewhat.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really complicated question, and it depends hugely on the circumstances.

However, the simple answer is "RDBMS engines are designed with the explicit goal of supporting many concurrent queries, and they are really good at that. There are cases where you run into performance issues due to concurrent access, but they are uncommon on enterprise-grade hardware".

The more complex answer is:

In general, "read" queries can run concurrently without noticable performance impact as long as your system has sufficient resources (RAM and CPU, along with i/o bandwidth), and as long as those queries are fast (typically that means less than 1 second).

If you have queries that are slow on their own, running several at the same time may lead to a slowdown - slow queries tend to consume more resources (RAM, CPU, i/o), and contention for those resources can lead to a slowdown.

If you have "write" queries, depending on your transaction strategy, you may encounter situations where one query locks a table which another query is trying to read or write.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this :

```
UPDATE table1 WITH(NOLOCK) SET Column1='asc' WHERE ....
```